# В чем проблема выполнения git команды через php?

Tags: php, git, exec

Не могу побороть одну проблемку.

В терминале делаю `git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxx/yyy.git` - все корректно клонируется (ssh ключи установлены, все ок.) в том же каталоге пробую это сделать через php:

```
passthru('git clone git@bitbucket.org:xxx/yyy.git',$output);
```

и получаю на выходе 128 ошибку git. (exec дает тот же результат.) Клонирования не происходит. В чем ошибка?

Comment: Можете пропробовать добавить
`git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"`

Comment: Пользователь тот же или другой? Замените на shell_exec и покажите текст ошибки.

Comment: shell_exec выдала NULL. (user.name и user.email установлены) Куда еще копать?

Comment: whoami и exec('whoami') показало, что пользователь под которым запускается php действительно отличается от пользователя в терминале... Что тут можно сделать?

Comment: `sudo -u` но придётся прокидывать пароль

Comment: Виртуальный хостинг. sudo не вариант. Еще что то можно сделать кроме переноса тестового сервера на VDS?

Comment: Для начала понять зачем вы хотите делать такое странное, и что же вы на самом деле хотите получить…